# Magento - Change links in header

Tags: magento-1.8

I just started with magento. I try to replace the header links on the default page. I need to replace the text "My Cart" with the following font-awesome icon.

[image]

`<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>`

But I have no clue where I can change this, the documentation is complicated and not very beginner friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You have to create your own design and assign it in the backend . Then you have to create the following folder structure if it does not exist yet.

```
\app\design\frontend\yourDesign\default\template\page\template
```

Now create a file called `links.phtml` with the following content:

```
<ul class="links"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
   //insert links here
</ul>
```